# Installation of Database Engine Services failed - "SQL Server Browser service group does not exist"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, installation

I tried to install a new instance of SQL Server 2017 on a Windows Server 2016, but received an error:

> “The following error has occurred. SQL Server Browser service group does not exist. Check for earlier failures in the setup”.

The summary log file (shown at the end of my post) shows that installation of Database Engine Services failed.

One default instance (MSSQLSERVER) was already in-place on the Server with Standard Edition. I tried to install named-instance (PEGASUS), with an Express edition. I cannot use the existing instance for operational reasons. Also, this instance needs to log on as Local Service, when the other logs on as NT Service\MSSQLSERVER.

When I ran the SQL Server 2017 Setup, I forgot to do this using “Run as administrator”. Could this account for the problem? (I'm logged in as the “companyadmin” user).

The server is one of 3 domain controllers. I know SQL Server should not be installed on DCs, but for right now, having SQL Server on this server is a requirement.

I do not know if this is relevant, but the 2017 version of SQL Server is the only full SQL Server version installed, other than 2012 Native Client and 2014 Management Objects, but all security groups refer to 2005.

[image: Active Directory Users]

The [link to Microsoft](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=14.0.2002.14&EvtType=0x95534F0C%400x0AE0775A%401221%4051019&EvtType=0x95534F0C%400x0AE0775A%401221%4051019) in the summary.txt file does not work, so I can't find more information from Microsoft.

Any ideas on how to fix this please?

---

## Summary.txt

> Overall summary:   Final result:                  Failed: see details
>   below   Exit code (Decimal):           -2067413173   Start time:
>   2019-11-16 20:20:01   End time:                      2019-11-16
>   21:02:31   Requested action:              Install
>
> Setup completed with required actions for features. Troubleshooting
>   information for those features:   Next step for SQLEngine:       Use
>   the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this
>   feature, and then run the setup process again.
>
> Machine Properties:   Machine name:                  APPS   Machine
>   processor count:       8   OS version:                    Microsoft
>   Windows Server 2016 Standard (10.0.14393)   OS service pack:
>   OS region:                     United States   OS language:
>   English (United States)   OS architecture:               x64   Process
>   architecture:          64 Bit   OS clustered:                  No
>
> Product features discovered:   Product              Instance
>   Instance ID                    Feature
>   Language             Edition              Version         Clustered 
>   Configured   SQL Server 2017      MSSQLSERVER
>   MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER            Database Engine Services
>   1033                 Standard Edition     14.0.2002.14    No
>   Yes          SQL Server 2017      MSSQLSERVER
>   MSAS14.MSSQLSERVER             Analysis Services
>   1033                 Standard Edition     14.0.2002.14    No
>   Yes          SQL Server 2017
>   Client Tools Connectivity                1033
>   14.0.1000.169   No         Yes          SQL Server 2017                                                          Client Tools Backwards Compatibility     1033
>   14.0.1000.169   No         Yes          SQL Server 2017                                                          Integration Services                     1033                 Standard
>   Edition     14.0.2002.14    No         Yes
>
> Package properties:   Description:                   Microsoft SQL
>   Server 2017    ProductName:                   SQL Server 2017   Type: 
>   RTM   Version:                       14   SPLevel:
>   0   Installation location:         Z:\x64\setup\   Installation
>   edition:          Express
>
> Product Update Status:   None discovered.
>
> User Input Settings:   ACTION:                        Install
>   ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      false   AGTSVCACCOUNT:
>   NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE   AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
>   AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Disabled   ASBACKUPDIR:
>   Backup   ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
>   ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config   ASDATADIR:
>   Data   ASLOGDIR:                      Log   ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:
>   1   ASSERVERMODE:                  TABULAR   ASSVCACCOUNT:
>      ASSVCPASSWORD:                    ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:
>   Automatic   ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:               ASTELSVCACCT:
>      ASTELSVCPASSWORD:              
>   ASTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0   ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp
>   BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Disabled   CLTCTLRNAME:
>      CLTRESULTDIR:                     CLTSTARTUPTYPE:
>   0   CLTSVCACCOUNT:                    CLTSVCPASSWORD:
>      CLTWORKINGDIR:                 
>   COMMFABRICENCRYPTION:          0   COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL:        0
>   COMMFABRICPORT:                0   CONFIGURATIONFILE:
>   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Setup
>   Bootstrap\Log\20191116_202000\ConfigurationFile.ini   CTLRSTARTUPTYPE:
>   0   CTLRSVCACCOUNT:                   CTLRSVCPASSWORD:
>      CTLRUSERS:                        ENABLERANU:
>   true   ENU:                           true   EXTSVCACCOUNT:
>      EXTSVCPASSWORD:                   FEATURES:
>   SQLENGINE   FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0   FILESTREAMSHARENAME:
>      FTSVCACCOUNT:                     FTSVCPASSWORD:
>      HELP:                          false
>   IACCEPTPYTHONLICENSETERMS:     false   IACCEPTROPENLICENSETERMS:
>   false   IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  true   INDICATEPROGRESS:
>   false   INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\   INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           d:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\   INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             
>   INSTANCEDIR:                   D:\Opera3\SQLServer   INSTANCEID:
>   PEGASUS   INSTANCENAME:                  PEGASUS   ISMASTERSVCACCOUNT:
>   NT AUTHORITY\Network Service   ISMASTERSVCPASSWORD:            
>   ISMASTERSVCPORT:               8391   ISMASTERSVCSSLCERTCN:
>      ISMASTERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:        Automatic
>   ISMASTERSVCTHUMBPRINT:            ISSVCACCOUNT:
>   NT AUTHORITY\Network Service   ISSVCPASSWORD:                  
>   ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic   ISTELSVCACCT:
>      ISTELSVCPASSWORD:              
>   ISTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0   ISWORKERSVCACCOUNT:            NT
>   AUTHORITY\Network Service   ISWORKERSVCCERT:               
>   ISWORKERSVCMASTER:                ISWORKERSVCPASSWORD:
>      ISWORKERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:        Automatic
>   MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT:         0   MATRIXCMSERVERNAME:
>      MATRIXNAME:                       MRCACHEDIRECTORY:
>   NPENABLED:                     0   PBDMSSVCACCOUNT:
>      PBDMSSVCPASSWORD:              
>   PBDMSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0   PBENGSVCACCOUNT:
>      PBENGSVCPASSWORD:              
>   PBENGSVCSTARTUPTYPE:           0   PBPORTRANGE:
>      PBSCALEOUT:                    false   PID:
>   *****   QUIET:                         false   QUIETSIMPLE:                   false   ROLE:                             RSINSTALLMODE:
>   DefaultNativeMode   RSSVCACCOUNT:                  
>   RSSVCPASSWORD:                    RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:
>   Automatic   SAPWD:                         *****   SECURITYMODE:
>   SQL   SQLBACKUPDIR:                     SQLCOLLATION:
>   Latin1_General_CI_AS   SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT
>   AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE   SQLSVCINSTANTFILEINIT:         false
>   SQLSVCPASSWORD:                *****   SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:
>   Automatic   SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           QUEST01\questadmin,
>   QUEST01\Lynn.Banks   SQLTELSVCACCT:                 NT
>   Service\SQLTELEMETRY$PEGASUS   SQLTELSVCPASSWORD:              
>   SQLTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE:          Automatic   SQLTEMPDBDIR:
>      SQLTEMPDBFILECOUNT:            1   SQLTEMPDBFILEGROWTH:
>   64   SQLTEMPDBFILESIZE:             8   SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:
>      SQLTEMPDBLOGFILEGROWTH:        64   SQLTEMPDBLOGFILESIZE:
>   8   SQLUSERDBDIR:                     SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:
>      SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE: false   TCPENABLED:
>   0   UIMODE:                        Normal   UpdateEnabled:
>   true   UpdateSource:                  MU   USEMICROSOFTUPDATE:
>   false   X86:                           false
>
> Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20191116_202000\ConfigurationFile.ini
>
> Detailed results:   Feature:                       Database Engine
>   Services   Status:                        Failed   Reason for failure:
>   An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.   Next
>   Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the
>   error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
>   Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services
>   Instance Features   Component error code:          0x84C5C74B   Error
>   description:             SQL Server Browser service group does not
>   exist. Check for earlier failures in the setup.   Error help link:
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=14.0.2002.14&EvtType=0x95534F0C%400x0AE0775A%401221%4051019&EvtType=0x95534F0C%400x0AE0775A%401221%4051019
>
> Rules with failures:
>
> Global rules:
>
> Scenario specific rules:
>
> Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\140\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20191116_202000\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm

Comment: It looks like this server used to have a named instance of SQL Server 2005 called `SERVER02`, which was subsequently uninstalled.  If you really, really need to run two instances of SQL 2017 on you domain controller, you'll probably have to start off from scratch with a new DC replica on, and get the installations working before you migrate the databases over.

Answer (score 2):

As the few web pages I found about this problem did not exactly to match my case,  I tried something simple which would not risk the other, live, default instance.

I was able to reinstall the second instance with these steps:

- Uninstall the instance whose installation failed.
- Create a new security group for the  SQL Server Browser service, this time with the name of the current server APPS, not the suspected old server SERVER02. My new group was "SQLServer2005SQLBrowserUser$APPS". I suspect that the name always contains "2005", whichever version of SQL Server.
- Run SQL Server setup again, to install a new instance, taking the same steps as before. Though this time I did remember to run SQL Server setup as administrator, none of the web pages suggested this as a cause of the initial problem. This time round it worked without error.

Helpful web pages I found included:

- [SQL Install Error “SQL Server Browser Service Group Does Not Exist”](https://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000689)
- [SQL Server Browser service group does not exists. Check for earlier failures in the setup. during sql express 2008 R2 setup](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e9f6ca8f-0c7b-4ca5-8bc5-f03b7c1bfc21/sql-server-browser-service-group-does-not-exists-check-for-earlier-failures-in-the-setup-during?forum=sqlexpress)
- [Installation problems with SQL Server 2008 R2 Express](https://managingdevelopers.wordpress.com/2014/04/15/installation-problems-with-sql-server-2008-r2-express/)

Conclusions include:

- This is not peculiar to a specific version SQL Server
- All pages associate the error message with installing SQL Server on a Domain Controller (DC).